# How do I create an IDOMPathGeometryPtr without using the static rect method?

Tags: c++, pdf, mako-sdk

I'm trying to create an `IDOMPathGeometry` using the Mako SDK. I intend to fill it with my own geometry, but I can only find a static `create(...)` method that takes an `FRect`.

How can I create an empty `IDOMPathGeometry` that I can fill myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Mako SDK classes can be created using the `IJawsMako::createInstance(...)` method.

In this case, you'd use code similar to the following:

```
IDOMPathGeometryPtr pathGeometry = edlobj2IDOMPathGeometry(m_mako->createInstance(IDOMPathGeometry::classID()));
if (!pathGeometry)
{
    // Handle error
}
```